# Photoshop: How do I edit a path once it is closed?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, drawing, pen-tool

I have closed a path, and it now appears in my Paths pane. However, I have no idea how to go back and bring up the anchor points again in order to edit it. Having clicked on the path itself, it simply remains closed, with no anchor points...

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Direct Selection Tool to select and move anchor points around:

[image: Direct Selection Tool]

If you'd like to add or remove points from the path, you can use the Add/Delete Anchor Point tools

[image: Pen Tools]